# write lambda function to enable s3 public access block

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to  write a lambda function to enable Public access settings for all S3 buckets available in AWS account. As shown in below screenshot, I need lambda functions to enable below two settings
Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects
Remove public access granted through public ACLs

[image]

Comment: First of all, why do you need a lambda function? Is it a recurring process? Or is it one time?

Comment: this will be my recurring process i need to run such script as soon as new bucket is created and lambda function should trigger

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to simply **change the default settings** for this feature.

See: [How Do I Edit Public Access Settings for All the S3 Buckets in an AWS Account?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/block-public-access-account.html)

If you do wish to specifically modify the Block settings on a bucket, use [`put_public_access_block()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_public_access_block):

```
response = client.put_public_access_block(
    Bucket='string',
    ContentMD5='string',
    PublicAccessBlockConfiguration={
        'BlockPublicAcls': True|False,
        'IgnorePublicAcls': True|False,
        'BlockPublicPolicy': True|False,
        'RestrictPublicBuckets': True|False
    }
)
```

Comment: yes but i need to this "How Do I Edit Public Access Settings for All the S3 Buckets in an AWS Account?" thru lambda function whenever new bucket create lambda function should trigger with the settings.can anyone help me

Comment: No, you can go to the S3 console and change the **default** setting so that you do _not_ need to do it for every new bucket.